# jersy path param with AES encryption

Tags: spring-mvc, aes, jersey-2.0

I am using path param as a part of my api :
I am sending form a spring boot application to a another servlet with has jersey as a REST framework. 
when I am sending i am doing :

```
 final String encrypt = aes.encrypt(customerId);    
 restTemplate.exchange(basicUrl+"/customer/{customer}"+ "?q=3",HttpMethod.GET, stringHttpEntity, ListingDto.class, encryptedcustomer);
```

and in the other side there is path param :

```
@GET
@Path("/customer/{customerId}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getLocationsByAccount(@QueryParam("q") String filter)
```

the problem is that the string which describe encryptedcustomer has inside / aign , so the jersey mapping dont know how to handle it , any thoughts how to do it right ?

Answer (score 2):

You are sending the encrypted value inside the url so you can't use special characters as "/". You have to options:

- Change the servlet (if possible) to accept POST method.
- Escape the characters to ensure that you are sending a valid request. See here for a detailed examples [When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/when-are-you-supposed-to-use-escape-instead-of-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)